# UISegmentedControl crashes if app installed using release config

Tags: ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I add UISegmentedControl in header view of the 1st section in table and it works fine in simulator or on iPad in debug mode. However, if I produce an archive for over-the-air distribution (that uses release config) and install it on iPad then when I try using Segmented Control it freezes (it does not switch to the chosen segment and method associated with UISegmentedControl does not get executed either) and then app crashes.

So, it has to be the difference between debug and release configuration, so I investigated it and found that if in PROJECT\TARGETS\Apple LLVM6.1 config\Optimization Level\ I change value for my distribution from (Fastest,Smallest) to what I have for debug (None), then UISegmentedControl begins to work fine!

Has anybody seen that or have other suggestion beside meddling with optimization level.

iPad iOS8.1, XCode 6.4

here is my code, though it seems like the problem is not there:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
    UIView *header = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18.0, 51.0, 100.0, 37.0)];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    headerLabel.text = @"IMAGE";
    [header addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];

    UISegmentedControl *actionSwitcher0 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Event", @"Question"]];
    [actionSwitcher0 setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 140, 28)];
    [actionSwitcher0 addTarget:self action:@selector(changeActionType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    actionSwitcher0.tag=1235;
    [header addSubview:actionSwitcher0];
    [actionSwitcher0 release];

    return header;
    }
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Set check for zombies and watch for your console

Comment: but would not that run debug config that works fine

Comment: You have a problem in debug and release. In debug it just did not occurs. 
Zombie detection can help find out where is your memory is broken. I guess you have some object without references. Consumed memory still not occupied by another objects and it works in debug.  And your code can use that object. It's called zombie. Object is still in memory but memory is considered as free and can be allocated for different object. As it happens and your code attempt to use your zombie object  - you have a crash